# Page hangs with Angularjs Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

for some reason my webpage hangs when I load my directive into the html. So instead of printing 'Dashboard', it's just blank. When I remove the directive call,  , it works fine. Am I not defining the directive properly?

I uploaded my code to Github: [Project](https://github.com/shahaba/Omicron.git)

---

HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lab Safety</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <projects></projects>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Directive:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
    .module('userdashApp.projects.directives')
    .directive('projects', projects);

function projects(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template/projects.html'
    }
}
})();
```

---

Directive Html:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
  <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks fine at first glance, do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Not atm, but i can learn how to and do it

Comment: looks fine. Is there any error on the console log? (press F12 in browser)

Comment: @lcycool, that's the weird thing, the console doesn't throw any errors. But let me see if I can set up fiddle

Comment: Have you injected the userdashApp.projects.directives into your main application?

Comment: I couldn't get all the code on fiddle, so I uploaded it to github. This code is at /static/javascript/userdash. @TjGienger, I registered it to my projects module, that I injected into my main userdashApp application.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to initiate your module:

```
angular
    .module('userdashApp.projects.directives', [])
    ...
```

Comment: I didn't post the code, but the initiation is handled in my module file js